# Why is my R dataframe not being copied in ifelse statement?

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

I have a dataframe *tas_i* with 875000 rows as below:

```
    head(tas_i)

  x tas year month_no
1 1  NA 1884        1
2 2  NA 1884        1
3 3  NA 1884        1
4 4  NA 1884        1
5 5  NA 1884        1
6 6  NA 1884        1
```

I have a relatively simple *ifelse* statement that just doesn't work (see below).  What am I doing wrong? My object *tas* ends up being a 'list' of numbers and not a 'dataframe'.

```
> i
[1] 1
> j
[1] 1884
> tas <- ifelse(i==1 & j==1884, tas_i, rbind(tas,tas_i))
> nrow(tas_i)
[1] 875000
> nrow(tas)
NULL
> tas_i[1:6,]
  x tas year month_no
1 1  NA 1884        1
2 2  NA 1884        1
3 3  NA 1884        1
4 4  NA 1884        1
5 5  NA 1884        1
6 6  NA 1884        1
> tas[1:6,]
Error in tas[1:6, ] : incorrect number of dimensions
class(tas)
[1] "list"
> class(tas_i)
[1] "data.frame"
```

Note that if I perform *tas <- tas_i*, it works fine and *tas* is a dataframe

```
tas <- tas_i
class(tas)
[1] "data.frame"
```

*emphasized text*

Comment: Are you using this in a loop? What is your final goal here?

Comment: I solved this by changing the ifelse statement to if (i==1 & j==1884) tas <- tas_i else tas <- rbind(tas,tas_i).  There must be a quirky thing about ifelse that returns a list.

Comment: Yes, this will be in a for..next loop

Comment: If you solved this yourself you can add it as an answer below.